# When I using YOLO V3, how can i save detected object name with .txt file?

Tags: yolo

I am first using YOLO V3 for my project. I had finished testing detecting dog. horse... etc. But I only got images result. I want to get detected object's name as
txt file. For Example, I tested dog.jpg and there is a txt file created. inside of txt file, it written "dog".

help me how can I get Object's name result by with txt file.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the source code, try to use this popular repository https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet which has a feature to save the detection result's information

Example : To process a list of images `data/train.txt` and save results of detection to `result.txt` use:

```
./darknet detector test cfg/voc.data yolo-voc.cfg yolo-voc.weights -dont_show -ext_output < data/train.txt > result.txt
```

Now you can open the result.txt and see all information related to your detection result